# Problema con acentos al recargar forma en JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

tengo una aplicación que baja un archivo con el componente filedownload de primefaces, tuve algunos problemas pero se solucionaron con ayuda aquí, ahora tengo otro problema, el botón de Descarga esta junto con un formulario de Edición, cuando se carga la pagina, se cargan bien los campos, al descargar el archivo, esto hace que se actualice la pagina y los campos, pero al hacer esto, me manda un mensaje diciendo que el formato de algunos campos no es válido, Debugeando vi que al hacer el update de la forma, los campos que marca inválidos es porque llevan acentos y los está cargando con caracteres raros, pero la primera vez que se cargan salen bien los acentos.

Alguna idea que podría hacer?

Disculpen, acá el código, no tenía acceso a el hasta ahora, el problema es con la Descarga, al actualizar la forma, los campos que tienen información y que llevan acentos, cuando se actualiza, indica que no tienen el formato válido y los deja en blanco y al hacer Debug, veo que los trae con símbolos

Mi XHTML

```html
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml">

 <ui:define name="content">
  <div class="ui-g">
   <div class="ui-g-12">
    <div class="card centerText">

     <h:form id="formaUpdate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />
     <h1>ACTUALIZAR RESGUARDO</h1>
     
     <input type="hidden" name="nombreUserLog" id="nombreUserLog" value="#{loginMB.nombre}" />
     
     <h:inputHidden id="idResguardo" value="#{resguardoMB.idResguardo}"/>
     <h:inputHidden id="rutaFormato" value="#{resguardoMB.rutaFormato}"/>
     <h:inputHidden id="nombreUserLogEdit" value="#{loginMB.nombre}"/>
     
     <p:panel header="Información del Equipo y Asignación">
     <p:panelGrid columns="4" layout="grid" style="width: 100%" cellpadding="5" styleClass="alignLeft">
     
      <h:outputLabel for="tipoResguardo" value="Tipo de Resguardo * " />
      <h:outputLabel for="numSerie" value="Número de Serie *" />
      <h:outputLabel for="marcaComputadora" value="Marca de Computadora *" />
      <h:outputLabel for="otraMarca" value="Otra Marca" />
            
      <p:selectOneMenu id="tipoResguardo" value="#{resguardoMB.tipoResguardo}">
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{resguardoMB.tipoResguardo}" itemValue=""/>
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="Usuario" itemValue="Usuario"/>
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="TI" itemValue="TI"/>
      </p:selectOneMenu>
      <p:inputText id="numSerie" required="true" value="#{resguardoMB.numSerie}"></p:inputText> 
      <p:selectOneMenu id="marcaComputadora" value="#{resguardoMB.marcaComputadora}">
       <f:selectItem itemValue="#{resguardoMB.marcaComputadora}" itemLabel="#{resguardoMB.marcaComputadora}" />
       <f:selectItems value="#{catcontenidoMB.catalogoMarcasComp}" var="marcas" itemValue="#{marcas.nombre}" itemLabel="#{marcas.descripcion}"/>
      </p:selectOneMenu>
      <p:inputText id="otraMarca" value="#{resguardoMB.otraMarca}"></p:inputText>
            
      <h:outputLabel for="sistemaOperativo" value="Sistema Operativo *" />
      <h:outputLabel></h:outputLabel>
      <h:outputLabel for="tipoComputadora" value="Tipo de Computadora *" />
      <h:outputLabel for="modeloComp" value="Modelo de Computadora *" />
            
      <p:selectOneMenu id="sistemaOperativo" value="#{resguardoMB.sistemaOperativo}">
       <f:selectItem itemValue="{resguardoMB.sistemaOperativo}" itemLabel="{resguardoMB.sistemaOperativo}" />
       <f:selectItems value="#{catcontenidoMB.catalogoSistOp}" var="sist" itemValue="#{sist.nombre}" itemLabel="#{sist.descripcion}"/>
      </p:selectOneMenu>
      <h:outputLabel></h:outputLabel>
      <p:selectOneMenu id="tipoComputadora" value="#{resguardoMB.tipoComputadora}">
       <f:selectItem itemValue="#{resguardoMB.tipoComputadora}" itemLabel="#{resguardoMB.tipoComputadora}" />
       <f:selectItems value="#{catcontenidoMB.catalogoTiposComp}" var="tipos" itemValue="#{tipos.nombre}" itemLabel="#{tipos.descripcion}"/>
      </p:selectOneMenu>
      <p:inputText id="modeloComp" required="true" value="#{resguardoMB.modeloComp}"></p:inputText>
            
      <h:outputLabel for="memoriaRam" value="Memoria RAM *" />
      <h:outputLabel for="valorCompra" value="Valor de Compra *" />
      <h:outputLabel for="userAsign" value="Staff Asignado *" />
      <h:outputLabel for="jefeUserAsign" value="Jefe Directo " />
            
      <p:inputText id="memoriaRam" required="true" value="#{resguardoMB.memoriaRam}"></p:inputText>
      <p:inputText id="valorCompra" required="true" value="#{resguardoMB.valorCompra}"></p:inputText>
      <p:selectOneMenu id="idUserAsign" value="#{resguardoMB.idUserAsign}">
       <f:selectItem itemValue="#{0}" itemLabel="#{resguardoMB.userAsign}" />
       <f:selectItems value="#{usersMB.usersList}" var="userasign" itemValue="#{userasign.id_users}" itemLabel="#{userasign.nombre}"/>
      </p:selectOneMenu>
      <p:selectOneMenu id="idJefeUserAsign" value="#{resguardoMB.idJefeUserAsign}">
       <f:selectItem itemValue="#{0}" itemLabel="#{resguardoMB.jefeUserAsign}" />
       <f:selectItems value="#{usersMB.usersList}" var="jefe" itemValue="#{jefe.id_users}" itemLabel="#{jefe.nombre}"/>
      </p:selectOneMenu>
      
      <h:outputLabel for="ubicacionUserAsign" value="Ubicación " />
      <h:outputLabel for="fechaAsignacion" value="Fecha de Asignación " />
      <h:outputLabel for="motivoAsignacion" value="Motivo de Asignación *" />
      <h:outputLabel></h:outputLabel>
      
      <p:selectOneMenu id="ubicacionUserAsign" value="#{resguardoMB.ubicacionUserAsign}" escape="false" >
       <f:selectItem itemValue="#{resguardoMB.ubicacionUserAsign}" itemLabel="#{resguardoMB.ubicacionUserAsign}" />
       <f:selectItems value="#{catcontenidoMB.catalogoUbicaciones}"
        var="ubic" itemValue="#{ubic.nombre}"
        itemLabel="#{ubic.descripcion}" />
      </p:selectOneMenu>
      <p:calendar id="fechaAsignacion" value="#{resguardoMB.fechaAsignacion}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" mask="true" />
      <p:selectOneMenu id="motivoAsignacion" value="#{resguardoMB.motivoAsignacion}" >
       <f:selectItem itemValue="#{resguardoMB.motivoAsignacion}" itemLabel="#{resguardoMB.motivoAsignacion}" />
       <f:selectItems value="#{catcontenidoMB.catalogoMotivAsign}" var="motiv" itemValue="#{motiv.nombre}" itemLabel="#{motiv.descripcion}"/>
      </p:selectOneMenu>
      <h:outputLabel></h:outputLabel>
      
     </p:panelGrid>
     </p:panel>
     
     <p:panel header="Adicionales">
     <p:panelGrid columns="4" layout="grid" style="width: 100%" cellpadding="5" styleClass="alignLeft">
           
      <p:inputTextarea id="comentarios" rows="5" cols="30" value="#{resguardoMB.comentarios}" counter="contador" maxlength="150" counterTemplate="{0} caracteres restantes. " autoResize="false" />
         <p:commandButton value="ACTUALIZAR" action="#{resguardoMB.updateResguardo}" update="growl"></p:commandButton>
         <p:commandButton rendered="#{loginMB.resguardo_rol eq ('SUPERADMIN' or 'ADMIN')}" value="DESCARGAR ARCHIVO" actionListener="#{resguardoMB.descargarFormato}" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);" update="@form">
      <p:fileDownload value="#{resguardoMB.archivoDescarga}" />
     </p:commandButton>
      <p:button value="INICIO" outcome="index"></p:button>
                     
         <h:outputText id="contador" /> 
         <h:outputLabel></h:outputLabel>
      <h:outputLabel></h:outputLabel>
      <h:outputLabel></h:outputLabel>
      
     </p:panelGrid>
         <p:fileUpload id="archivoFormato" rendered="#{loginMB.resguardo_rol eq ('SUPERADMIN' or 'ADMIN')}" fileUploadListener="#{resguardoMB.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" update="growl" multiple="false"
                   sizeLimit="1048576"
                   allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf)$/"
                   uploadLabel="Cargar" cancelLabel="Cancelar" label="Buscar archivo"/>
               <h:outputLabel></h:outputLabel> 
     </p:panel>
     </h:form>

    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function start() {
      PF('statusDialog').show();
  }
   
  function stop() {
      PF('statusDialog').hide();
  }
  </script>

 </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Mi Managed Bean

```
public void descargarFormato() throws Exception {

    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    String rutaFormatoasign = ec.getRequestParameterMap().get("formaUpdate:rutaFormato");

    File origen = new File(rutaFormatoasign);
    String nombre = origen.getName();
    File destino = new File("C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/webapps/ResguardosLat-1.0/resources/" + "archivoDescarga.pdf");

    try {
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(origen);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destino);

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;

            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }

            in.close();
            out.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    rutaFormato = rutaFormatoasign;
    InputStream stream = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/resources/" + "archivoDescarga.pdf");
    setArchivoDescarga(new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/pdf", nombre));
}
```

Gracias a todos

Comment: Alguien sabrá alguna ayuda? He estado buscando y no encuentro ninguna solución

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya quedó resuelto, por si alguien tiene el mismo problema, la raíz del mismo está en las llamadas Ajax, cuando se hace el refresh toma lo que está en el formulario, pero lo toma como input de HTML.

La solución es crear un Filtro para forzar el UTF en el request, en este post está la solución

https://zenidas.wordpress.com/recipes/avoid-encoding-problems-during-ajax-call-in-a-jsf-application/

Saludos